# Mysterious Ports on Oscilloscope

Tags: oscilloscope, banana-jack

I have an old Protek P-3502C Oscilloscope that I picked up second hand from my school. It has proven to be a great way to learn how to use oscillocopes, and has helped me with diagnostics as well.

But for as long as I have had it, I have had no clue what a couple of things on it are.

The first off is a section labeled `COMP. TEST` It has a single banana jack, and a button labeled in and out. (see image).

The other thing is two holes on the botton labeled `CH A STEP BAL` and `CH B STEP BAL`. (see image) From what I can tell from [this](http://www.1acal.de/Oscilloscopes%20and%20their%20Calibration-Web.pdf) document, it keeps the line from jumping around when I vary the volts/div scale. Is that correct?

`COMP. TEST` Connection

[image: Comp Test]

`STEP BAL` Holes

[image: BAL]

Comment: @EugeneSh. So it basically keeps the line from shifting when I change the Y axis scale

Comment: I would guess the "COMP TEST" is a probe compensation tester.  If you touch the probe to the inside of the jack, does a square wave appear on the screen?

EDIT:  Don't do that.  It's actually a component tester.

http://phys114115lab.capuphysics.ca/App%20J%20-%20oscilloscope/Osc%20Protek.htm

Comment: @ChrisM. No Square wave, I have a .5V 1khz can line on the oscilloscope as well, but there is a sine wave if the button is pressed in.

Comment: @ChrisM. Well I probed it, what do I do with that port.

Comment: Looks like you can put a diode, cap, resistor, or transistor between that port and the ground terminal and the scope will show you an I-V curve on the screen.

Just touching the probe to the port shouldn't do anything.

Comment: @ChrisM. I just figured it out myself. Pretty neat. Any clue what the in/out button is for? (Besides turning off the waveform)

Comment: I think it toggles the scope between component test and normal operation.  Component test would, I think, be "out" (scope provides the signal), and scope would be "in" (scope measures the signal).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60852/discussion-between-user173724-and-chris-m).

Comment: HP and Tek never needed that option, so I have to think it is part of the cheap scope calibration.  Normally a 1vpp square wave is the test signal is used to calibrate probes this may be for the vertical amp. in/OUT.  You'll figure it out.  More useful is the B invert and A+B mode with two probes calibrated and flat lined on same signal to ensure 0V in A_B mode then move one probe to get drop voltage  and read current etc.

Answer (score 3):

```
COMP. TEST
```

This is a simple component tester.  Just connect up the component(s), set channel A for 2V / div, channel B for 5V / div and press the button.  You can see the capabilities here:-

```
  Circuit      Large      Medium      Small
```

[image: testing]

Not sure of the value of this feature these days with disposable parts.  Modern scopes don't have them.

Comment: Someone in commends clarified this, can you add a little bit about step balance, and I will mark this as correct.

Comment: This is a fairly limited version of the test capabilities of something like a Huntron Tracker, for in-circuit, power off tests of things.  Huntron has a good write up on exactly how it works here: http://www.huntron.com/sales-support/pdf/ASA-paper-extract.pdf

Comment: @user173724 No, sorry.  That's all I've got unfortunately.  What about half a tick?  Up vote some of my other answers? I will add this though.  My Hameg 203 is old and analogue but doesn't have these _step_ adjustments.  So only some 'scopes have them...